# Why does the pattern package fails to be imported in jupyter notebook yet it is already installed

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

I installed pattern3 in the cmd with: `pip install pattern3`

and it was successful I also installed in the jupyter notebook and still it was successful.
However, when I try to import it with `import patterns` I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2116/1948699844.py in <module>
----> 1 import patterns

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'patterns'
```

Comment: The [examples in the `pattern3` PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/pattern3/) say e.g. `from pattern.web import Twitter`; you're trying to import `patterns` (a different word altogether).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have made a typo. The import statement for the pattern3 module would be `import pattern3`, not `import patterns`.

If you have installed the pattern3 module correctly, you should be able to import it by using the new statement.

Comment: Nice to hear, could you please accept the answer if it fulfills your needs so other people who might have the same problem find this solution quicker?